# Sharepoint 2016 crashes after MS Office 2016 64bit installation

Tags: sharepoint-server, ms-office

everyone.

Have been stumbled upon a very unusual issue - after MS Office installation all web applications (bad practice, i know), including central admin, return a 503 error. Reason is application pools in stopped condition. Any attempt to start up application pool fails.

There are no errors in Sharepoint Logs - only in event viewer. This and this

*Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.2457, time stamp: 0x5b7e2adb
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x0000000000033c58
Faulting process id: 0x1fcc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d63281c5b132ed
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ef188be8-b68e-4cbd-b7e3-82279f93967e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:*

and this

*The Module name SharePoint14Module path C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\isapi\owssvr.dll returned an error from registration.  The data is the error.*

I looked up a little bit - Enable 32-bit application is set to false, manipulations with ApplicationHost.config doesn't bring anything.

Does anyone have any idea what is source of this troubles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported to install Office on a SharePoint Server. See [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements).

You should deploy new SharePoint servers to the farm, migrate service instances, move your DNS record(s) to new FEs, then remove the now broken servers from the farm.

Office installs binaries in the GAC which conflict with the SharePoint binaries.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Well, so adding new server to a farm is sole solution to this problem? There are no other ways?

Comment: There's no other clean ways of getting back to a good state.

Comment: I had the same trouble. But I uninstalled Office and, fortunately, that was enough to get the SharePoint farm back to a good state.

Answer (score 0):

Check the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\16.0\Location`

It should point to the right location, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\`

This value gets overwritten after MS Office 2016 (or MS Office 2016 update) installation and causing exact symptoms you describe.